# Extract data from a list Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of string and I want to take the last "word" of it, explanation :

Here's my code :

```
myList = ["code 53 value 281", "code 53 value 25", ....]
```

And I want to take only the number at the end :

```
myList = ["281", "25", ....]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Break down the problem. You've got a list of strings, and you want the last word in a string. Iterate on the list, split the strings within it by `' '`, then get the last word from there.

Comment: You can iterate over your list and extract the number with Regex: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down your problem.

So first off, you've got a list of strings. You know that each string will end with some kind of numeric value, you want to pull that out and store it in the list. Basically, you want to get rid of everything except for that last numeric value.

To write it in code terms, we need to iterate on that list, split each string by a space character `' '`, then grab the last word from that collection, and store it in the list.

There are quite a few ways you could do this, but the simplest would be list comprehension.

```py
myList = ["Hey 123", "Hello 456", "Bye 789"] # we want 123, 456, 789

myNumericList = [x.split(' ')[-1] for x in myList]
# for x in myList is pretty obvious, looks like a normal for loop
# x.split(' ') will split the string by the space, as an example, "Hey 123" would become ["Hey", "123"]
# [-1] gets the last element from the collection

print(myNumericList) # "123", "456", "789"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to check if there are integers in your text, extract them and then convert them back to a string and add to a list. Anyhow, you can use .split() to split the text on spaces and then try to interpret the splitted strings as integers, like so:

```
myList = ["code 53 value 281", "code 53 value 25"]

list = []

for var in myList:
    list.append(var.split()[-1])

print(list)
```

Comment: OP doesn't say they want integers, OP wants *to take the last "word" of it*. For the specific example chosen, OP used numbers, but that's not necessarily the intended use case.

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the list and for a particular value at i-th index in the list simply pick the last value.

See code section below:

```py
ans=[]
for i in myList:
  ans.append(i.split(" ")[-1])
print(ans)
```

Comment: This code doesn't populate `ans`. Perhaps you meant `ans.append` instead of `myList.append`?

Comment: yes, by mistakenly i typed mylist instead of ans thanks for highlighting @Frontear